# Combine two lists and sort them

Tags: python, list, sorting, append

Lets say I have two lists. I want to append `list2` into `list1` and then sort and add a new element at a specific index.
I keep getting an error message saying:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

This is what I have tried:

```
list1 = [11, -21, 23, 45, 66, -93, -21]
list2 = [15, 67, -40, -21, 10]
list1.append(list2)
list1.insert(4, 50)
print(list1.sort())
```

Comment: You need `list1.extend(list2)` not `append`

Comment: Also, `sort` returns `None` so, `print(list1.sort())` won't print anything.

Comment: Your text says you want to sort then insert, but your code does insert then sort.  Which is it?

Comment: @MarkRansom, I should have written it in the order the code was in. Sorry for any confusion, I will edit the question. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sorted()` if you want to print sorted list:

```
list1 = [11, -21, 23, 45, 66, -93, -21]
list2 = [15, 67, -40, -21, 10]
list1.insert(4, 50)
print(sorted(list1 + list2))

# [-93, -40, -21, -21, -21, 10, 11, 15, 23, 45, 50, 66, 67]
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `append`, use `extend`. You are adding the second list as an element on the first list

```
>>> list1 = [11, -21, 23, 45, 66, -93, -21]
>>> list2 = [15, 67, -40, -21, 10]
>>> list1.append(list2)
>>> list1
[11, -21, 23, 45, 66, -93, -21, [15, 67, -40, -21, 10]]
```

Also, `sort` doesn't return a `list`. It returns `None`.

```
>>> list1 = [11, -21, 23, 45, 66, -93, -21]
>>> list2 = [15, 67, -40, -21, 10]
>>> list1.extend(list2)
>>> list1
[11, -21, 23, 45, 66, -93, -21, 15, 67, -40, -21, 10]
>>> list1.insert(4, 50)
>>> list1
[11, -21, 23, 45, 50, 66, -93, -21, 15, 67, -40, -21, 10]
>>> list1.sort()
>>> list1
[-93, -40, -21, -21, -21, 10, 11, 15, 23, 45, 50, 66, 67]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `list1.append(list2)`, use this: `list1=list1+list2`.
You can also use `list1.extend(list2)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can combine two lists using the + operator:

```
my_list1 = [1, 2]
my_list2 = [3, 4]
combinedList = my_list1 + my_list2
```

To insert a new element, Just use .insert (with index and element)

```
combinedList.insert(0, 0)
```

Remeber that the Index is 0 based!